# Using Complex Numbers in ODE Problem returns Inexact Error

Tags: julia, scientific-computing, differentialequations.jl

I am trying to implement to Swing equation for a n-Machine system using Julia.
When i run the following code I get this Error Message:

```
LoadError: InexactError: Float64(0.0 + 1.0im)
in expression starting at /home/Documents/first_try.jl:61
Swing_Equation(::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Array{Float64,1}, ::Float64) at complex.jl:37
ODEFunction at diffeqfunction.jl:219 [inlined]
initialize!
```

The problem is occuring since I am using `du[3] = (u[3] * u[2]) * im` which can not be a `Float64` type. The code is working fine when I remove the `im` - but then it is not the model I want to implement anymore.

What way is there to work around my problem?

```
using Plots
using DifferentialEquations
inspectdr()

# Constants
P_m0  = 0.3                      # constant Mechanical Power
P_emax = 1
H = 1.01                         # Inertia constant of the system
θ_0 = asin(P_m0 / P_emax)        # angle of the system
ω_0 = 1.0                        # initial angular velocity
M = 2 * H / ω_0
D = 0.9                          # Damping constant

u02 = [θ_0;ω_0]                  # Initial Conditions
tspan = (0.0,100.0)              # Time span to solve for
p = [M;P_m0;D]  
i = 3

function Swing_Equation(du,u,t,p)                # u[1] = angle θ
    du[1] = u[2]                                 # u[2] = angular velocity ω
    P_e = real(u[3] * conj(i))
    du[2] = (1 / M) * ( P_m0 - P_e - D * u[2])   # du[2] = angular acceleration
    du[3] = (u[3] * u[2]) * im
end

# solving the differential equations

prob2 = ODEProblem(Swing_Equation,u0,tspan,p)
print(prob2)
sol2 = solve(prob2)

# Visualizing the solutoins
plot(sol2; vars = 1, label = "Θ_kura", line = ("red"))
plot!(sol2; vars = 2, label = "ω_kura", line = ("blue"))
gui()

plot(sol2,vars = (1,2),label="Kurmamoto" ,line = ("purple"))
xlabel!("Θ")
ylabel!("ω")
gui()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is most likely in your input.

```
prob2 = ODEProblem(Swing_Equation,u0,tspan,p)
```

I am guessing that in this part you are providing an array of `Float64` for `u0`? Your `Swing_Equation` then receives `u` as an `Array{Float64}` type. I suspect that also means `du` is the same.

This causes the expression

```
du[3] = (u[3] * u[2]) * im
```

to fail because you are trying to assign a `Complex{Float64}` number to `du[3]` which is of type `Float64`. Julia will then try to perform a

```
convert(Float64, (u[3] * u[2]) * im)
```

Which will cause the inexact error, because you cannot convert a complex number to a floating point number.

The Solution is to make sure `du` and `u` are complex numbers so you avoid this conversion. A quick and dirty way to solve that would be to write:

```
prob2 = ODEProblem(Swing_Equation, collect(Complex{Float64}, u0),tspan,p)
```

This will collect all elements in `u0` and create a new array where every element is a `Complex{Float64}`. However this assumes a 1D array. I don't know your case. I don't work with ODE solvers myself.

### General Advice to avoid this kind of problem

Add some more type assertions to in your code to make sure you get the kind of inputs you expect. This will help catch these kinds of problem and make you more easily see what is going on.

```
function Swing_Equation(du::AbstractArray{T}, u::AbstractArray{T}, t,p) where T<:Complex               # u[1] = angle θ
    du[1] = u[2] :: Complex{Float64}
    P_e = real(u[3] * conj(i))
    du[2] = (1 / M) * ( P_m0 - P_e - D * u[2])   # du[2] = angular acceleration
    du[3] = (u[3] * u[2]) * im
end
```

Keep in mind Julia is a bit more demanding when it comes to matching up types than other dynamic languages. That is what gives it the performance.

### Why is Julia different from Python in this case?

Julia does not upgrade types like Python to whatever fits. Arrays are typed. They cannot contain anything like in Python and other dynamic languages. If you e.g. made an array where each element is an integer, then you cannot assign float values to each element without doing an explicit conversion to floating point first. Otherwise Julia has to warn you that you are getting an inexact error by throwing an exception.

In Python this is not a problem because every element in an array can be a different type. If you want every element in a Julia array to be a different number type then you must create the array as a `Array{Number}` type but these are very inefficient.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer Erik! This solved my problem and I now have a better understanding for using types in Julia!

Comment: Indeed, DifferentialEquations.jl very much respects your type choices, and for good reason. There are cases where defining simulations over integers makes sense (Gillespie-SSA), or using Float32 values (neural networks embedded within the ODE), or arbitrary precision, etc. So we respect and use whatever type you set as `u0` as the type for states. If you want it complex, you should make it complex. This is definitely a case where if we tried to be too smart we'd break a lot, so it's really up to the user to give an appropriate input.